# ordering query results with two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

```
Reply_ID | Fk_Post_ID
   10    |    5
   9     |    6
   8     |    5
   7     |    9
   6     |    5
   5     |    9
   4     |    7
```

I need a query retrieves records in the following order pattern. it searches for the record with the highest reply_ID then retrieves all records having the same Fk_Post_ID. something like this:

```
Reply_ID | Fk_Post_ID
   10    |    5
   8     |    5
   6     |    5
   9     |    6
   7     |    9
   5     |    9
   4     |    7
```

Comment: I think if you extend the example with the rows (5, 9) and (4, 7) it would be clearer what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #YourTable (
    Reply_ID INT,
    fk_Post_ID INT
)

INSERT INTO #YourTable VALUES (10, 5)
INSERT INTO #YourTable VALUES (9, 6)
INSERT INTO #YourTable VALUES (8, 5)
INSERT INTO #YourTable VALUES (7, 9)
INSERT INTO #YourTable VALUES (6, 5)


SELECT
    t1.Reply_ID, 
    t1.fk_Post_ID
FROM
    #YourTable t1 JOIN (
    SELECT 
        MAX(Reply_ID) AS Max_Reply_ID,
        fk_Post_ID
    FROM #YourTable
    GROUP BY fk_Post_ID
) t2 ON t2.fk_Post_ID = t1.fk_Post_ID
ORDER BY 
    t2.Max_Reply_ID DESC, 
    t1.Reply_ID DESC
```

[Sql Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7d65/1/0)

Comment: yes. it worked nicely. so it's a join with max(). i tried subquery in where clause but didn't work. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `CASE` in the `ORDER BY`:

```
....
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Fk_Post_ID=(
                   SELECT MIN(Fk_Post_ID)
                   FROM dbo.Table
                   WHERE Reply_ID=(SELECT MAX(Reply_ID)FROM dbo.Table)
               ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC
,  Reply_ID DESC
,  Fk_Post_ID ASC
```

Here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45f20/7/0

Comment: i tried it but didn't work. query results just like (order by reply_id, fk_post_id)

Comment: yes. but strangely it doesn't give me the same results on my db server

Answer (score 2):

If your DBMS has window functions then this will also solve it:

```
Select
  Reply_ID,
  FK_Post_ID
From 
  yourTable a
Order By 
  Max(Reply_ID) Over (Partition By FK_Post_ID) Desc,
  Reply_ID Desc
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4be0c/9/0